# Automatic Google Sheets authorization in RShiny

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, googlesheets4

I have an RShiny app that I had published online without any issues until this week. The app uses data stored in a Google Drive account, thus making use of the googlesheets package. When the app was working fine, I used `gs_auth()` to initially authorize and cache my Google credentials. Because my credentials were cached in a `.httr_oauth` in my working directory, it meant that when I ran the app's code, it wouldn't take me to a page in my browser that would ask me to authorize the account. When publishing the app to shiny.io, this cached `.httr_oauth` meant that the app would work online.

This week I made some changes to the app's code and when I ran the app it took me to the Google account authorisation page. There, I would click on the account and it would then say: "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app".

After some looking I found that the googlesheets package is now outdated and I should instead be using the googlesheets4 package. However, after trying to authorize with that package (and the googledrive package) I'm able to get the app to run locally without it taking me to the Google account authorization page, but when I try to publish it still doesn't work. It always times out. Does anyone know what is going on? Anyone else having a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well.

This outline worked really well for me.

https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html

I would focus on Project Level OAthu part of the vignette.

The biggest issues I had for switching from "googlesheet" to "googlesheets4" was I forgot to install the "googledrive" package. The googledrive will allow you to use (drive_auth) and then build out from there as you can cache the authentication token.

Comment: Hi could this be elaborated a bit more?